# Text Visibility is not working correctly second time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have WPF application where I want to show or hide some text when a button is clicked. Problem is when the button is clicked from the second time it never shows the text. Please help. Here is my xaml

```
<Button
            Grid.Column="1"
            x:Name="btnUpdateGrid"
            Margin="{StaticResource AllControlsMargin}"
            Content="{StaticResource UpdateGrid}" Click="btnUpdateGrid_Click"></Button>



            <TextBlock x:Name="tblWait" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="Hidden"
                Text="{StaticResource UpdatingImages}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
```

In the button click I am saying the following. The UpdatePlate2DView method takes a while to execute. And this is not multi threaded.

```
private void btnUpdateGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tblWait.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            UpdatePlate2DView();
            tblWait.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `async` and visual states ?

Comment: If it were me, I would just add the BooleanToVisibilityConverter (or Reverse converter depending on need), swap `Button` for `ToggleButton`, ditch the Click event on there and just do `<TextBlock Text="Peek-A-Boo!" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=btnUpdateGrid, Converter={StaticResource=BoolConverterKeyName}"/>` and be done with it...

Comment: Sure Chris good idea let me try like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "UpdatePlate2DView()" function might be doing some busy UI processing. So before call this function, call "System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()" to make application process any pending UI messages.